# Defining algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

can anyone give me an example of this algorithm? Can it be longest common increasing subsequence?

[image: algo]

Comment: Think about it: I cannot be the longest common increasing subsequence as this would require two sequences as input. However, here you only have a single input (even though the type of `v` remains unclear. Please specify the type). Also, we cannot really help you unless you show the definition of `c(u, v)`, `s`, and `E`. Please add them to your question by editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a minimum path length to reach v from s(starting point) where E is the set of edges from vertex u to vertex v.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an algorithm to find the shortest path in a graph.

d(v) is shortest path from vertex s to v moving along edges where the cost of an edge from u to v is c(u,v).